# Have nginx route upstream based on hostname

Tags: nginx

I am currently trying to make a nginx file that routes the request to the 1 of two upgstreams (local or away server) based on the host.  So for example I am trying the following

```
map $host $upstream_host {
    api.example.to api2.example.to;
    api.example2.to api2.example2.to;
    api.example3.to api2.example3.to;
    api.example4.to api2.example4.to;
}

upstream backend {
    ip_hash;
    server $upstream_host;
    server unix:/home/www/api.to/app.sock;


}

server {
    server_name api.example.to;
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But this errors out with `nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "$upstream_host" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/api.to.conf:18`

So I am not sure this is possible with nginx? Ie, I just want a requet sent to api.example.to to either be sent to the box locally or to api2.example.to, same for api.example2.to to be sent to api2.example2.to or the local unix server as a load balance.

The OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and nginx 1.18.  Note I get the same issue with nginx 1.22.1

Comment: Nginx totally can do this. Debian/Ubuntu do things a little differently, so including your is/distro would be useful

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I went ahead and added Ubuntu 20.04 and Nginx 1.18

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Not sure if that does it.  I have some one sending requests to say api.example and I want those requests to be routed to the local api.example or, using a load balancing, send to api2.example, does that make more sense?  In essence 50/50 to the local block and 50 to the away server

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle that seems like the exact same code i posted that doesnt work